# C#: Reading barcode sometimes does not fire keyboard keypress event

Tags: c#, barcode, keypress, barcode-scanner

I have a WinForms application which consists on one main form. This form has some controls such as labels, textboxes, pictureboxes, buttons, etc.

I have set to true form KeyPreview property in order to ensure that all keystrokes are seen in the form's keystroke keypress event before they are passed on to any control so I have subscribed to the keypress keyboard event handler to capture the barcode stream.

The barcode scanner is configured as a keyboard wedge.

When the form is completly loaded, I try to read the barcode using the scanner, and I have note that in some occasion the event is keyboard keypress event is not being fired. When this happens, if I click on the form or even I click on a textbox, or any other object on the form (label, picturebox, etc.) then It starts to work. Why?

On form load, some initialitzations are done and a background worker is created to do some stuff.

What can I do in order to ensure that on form load the form keypress event will always be fired when it detects barcode stream?

Comment: Without code we can't know what you're doing that hangs the keyboard events and thus we can't provide any solution. You should isolate what causes the events to not to be receiver and then if you still need help ask a more concrete question.

Comment: KeyPreview only ensures that the form's KeyDown event fires.  It does nothing to help KeyPress, that only ever gets fired on the control with the focus.  You must therefore ensure that the correct control always has the focus.  Consider a "scan mode" feature in your UI that pops up a dialog with only a single textbox.  Nothing left to guess at either for your user or you.

Comment: @HansPassant As far as I know from Microsoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx that says: "Gets or sets a value indicating whether the form will receive key events before the event is passed to the control that has focus." and in the remarks section: "When this property is set to true, the form will receive all KeyPress, KeyDown, and KeyUp events." So I understand that not only ensures that the form's KeyDown event fires but also KeyPress and KeyUp events.

Comment: That documentation is not correct.  As you found out.

Comment: @HansPassant so what would be the solution in order the form always get the keypress event, I mean, when any key is pressed?

Comment: I already told you, read my first comment again.